# How to constrantly refresh chart with new data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, setinterval, c3.js

I'm looking for appropriate way to refresh bar chart which is constantly getting data from API.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/data' //getting data from API
}).then(function ( json ) {
   //chart 
}
```

There is a similar situation on the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw8MEZaoAgLBw7i7ry5q?p=preview), but I'm affraid of memory leak with this method and chart is always blinking.

Do anyone has a suggestion what to use instead of interval? Or use it in some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `socket.io`?

Comment: What techonology do you use on backend ? (NodeJs, .Net, etc...)

Comment: I use NodeJS and socket.io for another functionality :) @Adam, is there any example how to use C3 with socket.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Plunker is great, but the problem is that it calls `c3.generate` continuously, which is why it's leaking memory and flashing (You're essentially creating a new C3 chart instance every time you run `generate`; all it does is called `new Chart(config);`)

What you need to do is instantiate C3 in the controller and then call `c3.load()` in your `$http` call.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wIIhiZLDcoJ2tbFiWs8O?p=preview)

Key bit:

```
  $interval(function() {
    $http.get('chartData.json')
      .then(function(json) {
        $scope.countries = formatData(json.data); // format received data
        $scope.chart.load({json: $scope.countries, keys: { value: ['Croatia', 'Belgium', 'Argentina'] }});
      });
  }, 1000);
```

The `$interval+$http` combo should work okay, provided that the JSON file you're loading is just on a CDN somewhere (if it's being generated on a per-request basis by a REST API, you'll either get throttled or rinse your server). You may want to take a look at [$http's caching docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching).